# How do I Google Search within my app from multiple text inputs

Tags: android, search, uitextfield

I'm trying to build an app in which a user inputs ingredients into multiple text fields displayed within my app. when the user presses enter all of their text is formatted as a Google search, my app would then open the default web-browser on the users phone and display a google search for recipes containing the ingredients that they entered.

So far I've tried the google custom search engine and I've been searching the internet for hours now on how I could go about actually building this. So any input or expertise you may have that could help me would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can open an intent with specified URL like this

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strURL));
startActivity(myIntent);
```

strURL can be constructed with appending

```
google.com/search?q=searchstring1+searchstring2
```

to your search string

EDIT:
`text1=editText1.getText();` and so on you can get text from different text inputs

`strURL=text1 + "+" + "text2" + "+" + text3;`

Comment: How is the strURL constructed? im assuming its done in java? would you mind posting some code.

Comment: 'EditText ingredient1;
Button button1;
public void ensureCapacity (int min) {
Editable text1=ingredient1.getText();
String strURL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=recipes-with" + text1 ; } 
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
button1.setOnClickListener(
         new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {   Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strURL)); startActivity(myIntent); }});}'

Comment: this is my code yet I've been playing around with it for a bit but im not entirely sure where i should be putting it inside my java. i keep getting either a runtime error an infinite loop error on the string. or it just plain doesn't work. could you please show me specifically where i should be putting this code. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just open a browser to `https://www.google.com/search?q=term1+term2+term3` where term1, term2, and term3 are the terms you want to search for (and of course you can add more).

Comment: Thanks! I'l give that a try hopefully it works I'l let you know.